# Vim - possible to 'Change 2nd Word In quotes'?

Tags: vim, textselection

This is arguably a micro-optimisation but given the following:

```
<div class="ClassOne ClassTwo">Content</div>
```

Using Vim, and with my cursor anywhere on that line, I wondered if there is a way to change the 2nd word in the quotes using the change action? I realise I can jump there and remove the word in a number of ways (<kbd>fTcaw</kbd> as one example) but wondered if there is a way using Change within a context (rather than just finding and changing that particular word)?

I tried <kbd>c2wi"</kbd> and <kbd>cw2i"</kbd> but no joy. Is there a way using 'change in' or does that always delete all content inside?

Comment: The text object is inner quotes. I don't think you can combine text object with motions (which is what it seems like you are trying to do). If you wanted you could write a custom text object.

Comment: OK, that was my suspicion. I'll have a look at writing a custom text object.

Answer (score 1):

**Example-Specific Solution:**

`$Bcw`

**More Generalized Solution:**

- `^` - reorient cursor from 'anywhere on that line' to the beginning
- `f"` - go to first quote, use `;` if needed to jump down a line with multiple quote blocks
- `W` - move to beginning of next WORD (one less key than `2w`)
- `cw` - change word

*Variations:*

- for the first word, use `w` instead of `W`
- for the third~nth word, use `w` multiple times or prefix it with a number, e.g. `3w`
- iterate backwards from the end of the quotes: `$F"b`

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a simple macro?

<kbd>qa</kbd> + do marko of your choice <kbd>0f"wwcw</kbd> + exit makro <kbd>q</kbd>

Call makro <kbd>@a</kbd> on any line.

Comment: Yes, that's a possibility but it's not an 'expressive' way to do it. For example, what if I want to change the 3rd word in quotes or 1st word in quotes. Was just wondering if there's a way to do it with Vim's core language.